# 3D Multi-touch Prototype for Augmented and Virtual Reality

Tags: computer-vision, augmented-reality

I'm not sure the question I ask falls under this category. However, I want to know how the **Prototype** for 3D Multi-touch Augmented and Virtual Reality (in the following video) is developed. What programming technology is used? What algorithms? I want to know in and out of this awesome technology.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw1mXjMshJE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much explained in the video description:

> In this video I demonstrate the 3D interaction prototype that I have developed during my Master Thesis at Fraunhofer FIT in Bonn, Germany. The system uses a depth sensing camera, which is based on the time-of-flight principle and measures phase shifts of a reflected infrared signal. My contribution is the computer vision algorithm, the gesture recognition technique as well as the concept and implementation of the demo application.

He uses a depth camera based on time-of-flight (i.e., same tech as the Kinect2) and is extracting the hands/fingers.  No idea if his computer vision algorithms for doing this are published, but you could get a good start with OpenCV.  Once you have the 3D information for the hands and fingers, the graphics part can be done using any 3D graphics programming environment (low-level OpenGL, Unity3D, etc).